# Validation list on vba corrupt file

Tags: excel, vba

I did some code and at some point i created an array and then use that array to feed a validation list in a cell, all work just fine but when i close the worksheet and then open it an error occur and i have to do some adjustment in order to use the macro again.
I read some tips on internet the easy way is to save the worksheet in binary mode, xlsb, the error occur but the worksheet is usable you have just to relaunch the macro.

what i was wondering is, is there a way to deal with this problem once for all?

here the screenshot about the error

[image]

here the description

[image]

here the code about the list

```
Sub filtroSwing()

 Dim mezzi As New Collection
 Dim tot As Range

 Set tot = Foglio3.Range("a1:a" & Foglio3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
 On Error Resume Next
  For i = 1 To tot.Rows.Count

     mezzi.Add tot.Cells(i, 1).Value, tot.Cells(i, 1).Value
 Next i

On Error GoTo 0

 Dim lista() As Variant

 ReDim lista(1 To mezzi.Count)


Dim temp As String



For i = 1 To mezzi.Count

    lista(i) = mezzi(i)
Next i


 'ordina

  For i = 1 To mezzi.Count - 1
        For j = i + 1 To mezzi.Count

         If lista(i) > lista(j) Then
               temp = lista(i)
               lista(i) = lista(j)
               lista(j) = temp
          End If
      Next j
  Next i
     

      Foglio7.Range("f1").Validation.Delete
      Foglio7.Range("f1").Validation.Add xlValidateList, Formula1:=Join(lista, ",")


    Foglio6.Range("u22").Validation.Delete
   Foglio6.Range("u22").Validation.Add xlValidateList,Formula1:=Join(lista, ",")

   end sub
```

thanks in advance

Cristiano

Comment: How large is the array? Where is the code and data we can use to reproduce your error? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: it's not too big its but it's variable, i' ll post the code

Comment: i did another try writing the array on the worksheet and then used the validation list on exel and all works fine the problem occur just when i use validation list on vba

Comment: Are all of the items in the list `Text`?   What is the range of "not too big"?

Comment: yes they are all string, it can be 60 items max

Comment: I have had problems with saving longish validation lists as vba arrays. I was told it was related to some issue with the underlying XML which is how xlsm files are stored.  Two possible solutions:  Save the file as an xlsb file, or put the validation list in a worksheet range (perhaps on a hidden or very hidden worksheet) and refer to that location.

Comment: Also, suggest that instead of `Dim mezzi As New Collection`, you write this as two lines: `Dim mezzi As Collection : Set mezzi = New Collection`  There are articles as to the benefits of the second method.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld yes if put the validation list it works, i 'll try set for new collection.

Comment: with xlsb i have the same problem but i need to launch the macro again and in order to restore the validation list.

Comment: In order to avoid to save the list on a sheet you can try the following : Place this code in "ThisWorkBook" modul `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)     Foglio7.Range("f1").Validation.Delete     Foglio6.Range("u22").Validation.Delete End Sub` and this code in the sheet modul `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Selection, Range("f1")) Is Nothing Then Call filtroSwing
End Sub`

Comment: @remyfra thanks to you i found what i needed i did like you said, with before close event, delete the validation list and with open event i remake the validation list and all work great, thanks for the tip

Comment: @CristianoMorresi Great! Cheers from Verona ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Join(lista, ",")` > then 255 characters, you will also have problems.

I suggest:

- create sorted `lista` as you have, but as a 2D array eg `lista(1 to mezzi.count, 1 to 1)`
- write `lista` to a range on a hidden worksheet.

  - `myRange = lista`
- then `.Formula1 = myRange`